# How to change data type from varchar to text?

Tags: hooks, emails

I'm trying to change the data type of column "mail" from table "simplenews_subscriber" from varchar to text using hook_update_N but its not getting reflected.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_schema().
 */
function simplenews_schema() {
  $schema['simplenews_subscriber'] = array(
    'description' => 'Subscribers to {simplenews_category}. Many-to-many relation via {simplenews_subscription}',
    'fields' => array(
      'snid' => array(
        'description' => 'Primary key: Unique subscriber ID.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'activated' => array(
        'description' => 'Boolean indicating the status of the subscription.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'size' => 'tiny',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'mail' => array(
        'description' => "The subscriber's email address.",
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 64,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
      'uid' => array(
        'description' => 'The {users}.uid that has the same email address.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'language' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 12,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
        'description' => 'Subscriber preferred language.',
      ),
      'timestamp' => array(
        'description' => 'UNIX timestamp of when the user is (un)subscribed.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'changes' => array(
        'description' => 'Contains the requested subscription changes',
        'type' => 'text',
        'serialize' => TRUE,
      ),
      'created' => array(
        'description' => 'UNIX timestamp of when the subscription record was added.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('snid'),
    'indexes' => array(
      'mail' => array('mail'),
      'uid' => array('uid'),
    ),
    'foreign keys' => array(
      'uid' => array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'columns' => array('uid' => 'uid'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

Update Hook:

```
function MY_MODULE_update_7001() {
  db_drop_index('simplenews_subscriber', 'mail');
  db_change_field('simplenews_subscriber', 'mail', 'mail', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'size' => 'medium',
    )
  );
}
```

Any help of this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing recreating the index.
Also you can use your schema changes:

```
$schema = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('my_module', 'simplenews_subscriber');
db_change_field('simplenews_subscriber', 'mail', 'mail', $schema['simplenews_subscriber']['fields']['mail']);
```

Another thing you can do is test out altering the table manually just so you can see what errors are popping up.